# Order by results are out-of-range when converting varchar to datetime with missing time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, varchar, outofrangeexception

I have a `varchar` row in a log-db that normally looks like `17.09.2020 00:00:01` and I can `CAST()` it to `datetime` and order by it without problems, e.g. this simplified query:

```
SELECT CAST(my_date_and_time AS datetime)
FROM my_table
ORDER BY CAST(my_date_and_time AS datetime) DESC
```

Now the problem is, that tonight I've got a log-entry at exactly 00:00:00 and the logging-script or database cut off the time from the `varchar` field and so now it only contains `17.09.2020` instead of `17.09.2020 00:00:00`.
When I try to cast this one to `datetime` it results in an out-of-range error, probably because the time part is missing?

Unfortunately I have no access to the logging script to change it there.
So is there any way to convert this to an useable format within the query?

**EDIT:** Here's an example of what the my_date_and_time row looks like:

```
|---------------------|
|   my_date_and_time  |
|---------------------|
| 17.09.2020 05:29:53 |
|---------------------|
| 17.09.2020 00:02:11 |
|---------------------|
|      17.09.2020     |  
|---------------------|
| 16.09.2020 23:59:38 |
|---------------------|
| 16.09.2020 23:59:18 |
|---------------------|
```

**EDIT2:** By further testing I was able to narrow the error further down. It is NOT because of the timestamp as initially assumed, which has no time information. The problem actually affects records that are not compliant.

**These data records are missing the preceding 0 for the month and one point is too much after the year.**
e.g. `16.9.2020. 14:22:23`

*I'm on the verge of ripping off the head of whoever programmed this ..*

Is there any conceivable way to get the correct values ​​back via query anyway?

Sorry for the misunderstandings and thanks to everyone who has contributed to solving the problem so far

Comment: The *real* question here is why are you storing dates as a `varchar`? There are plenty of Date and Time data Types to choose from and you should be using one of those. Fix the design fix the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However, the table was not created by me and it is currently not possible to edit it. So I have to try to make the best of it!

Comment: @Don if you have `my_date_and_time` stored as varchar, why do you not get error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."?

Comment: @Don let's try SELECT CAST(my_date_and_time AS date)

Comment: They do, @timnavigate . That's what the title says.

Comment: @Larnu oops, I'm inattentive. Well, then Don should use DATEFORMAT as solution specified by Sebastian Brosch in his answer

Comment: Neither CONVERT() nor DATEFORMAT solve the problem

Comment: @Don please show your varchar's data as example (any rows)

Comment: @timnavigate edited my post with row-info

Comment: @Don ***both*** `TRY_CONVERT` and `DATEFORMAT` work for the examples you have given us: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9246567c61ccc249df21d3083509fecc). The problem is the other **bad** data you have. Again, this just cements that you *must* fix your design.

Comment: We already provided some solutions to get this value as datetime. I can't reproduce your error at the moment. This value is fine. You get a result on this query: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ISDATE(my_date_and_time) = 0`?

Comment: @ALL As you all correctly recognized, the error is not, as previously suspected, due to the missing time. Sorry for the wrong assumption. I updated my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, really you should be fixing your data type.

If all your dates *are* in the format `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss` then you use use `CONVERT` and a style code to convert them regardless of settings:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime,Your_varchar,103)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

If any return `NULL` they either have the value `NULL`, or failed to convert.

But back to fixing your data.

Firstly, let's do this in a new column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD Actual_date_and_Time datetime NULL
```

Now we can `UPDATE` that value by coverting the value:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Actual_date_and_Time = TRY_CONVERT(datetime,Varchar_Date_and_time,103);
```

Then you can query an actual `datetime` column.

You can then review your new data and see if any if bad, and amend:

```sql
SELECT Varchar_Date_and_time
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Varchar_Date_and_time IS NOT NULL
  AND Actual_date_and_Time;
```

Then, finally, you can `DROP` the old column and rename the new one (if you want to):

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN Varchar_Date_and_time;
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable.Actual_date_and_Time',N'Varchar_Date_and_time','COLUMN';
```

Comment: I cannot edit the table at the moment, because several other programs read or save data here. Furthermore, I have no access to the script, which saves the time as a string, which is why the change would not be expedient.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `convert` function ([Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)):

```sql
declare @my_date_and_time  varchar(19) = '17.09.2020 00:00:01';

select convert(date, @my_date_and_time, 104)
```

or try to set `dateformat` as `dmy` (day/month/year):

```sql
set dateformat dmy

declare @my_date_and_time  varchar(19) = '17.09.2020 00:00:01';

select cast(@my_date_and_time as date)
```

Comment: Like I commented on the first answer from Sebastian Brosch, convert() instead of cast() and set dateformat didn't help