# SQL Server querying date issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, querying

I have a column called `CreatedDate` in my table. It's defined as datatype `VARCHAR` instead of `DateTime`.

I know for fact that there is a data which have greater date than 1/11/2023 but I'm not sure why it's not showing. It's returning/showing some random data from 2022.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE CreatedDate > '01/11/2023 12:15:32'
```

Comment: *"It's VARCHAR type instead of DateTime."* that's your problem. Fix the design. *" I'm not sure why it's not showing."* because your data type is wrong. *"It's returning/showing some random data from 2022."* Because the `varchar` value `'02/01/2022 00:00:00'` *is* **after** `'01/11/2023 12:15:32'`. `'1'` is less than `'2'`.

Comment: Hi Larnu, how can I change the type to DateTime?. If I did that then do you know if I might lose some data?.

Comment: You might well do, yes, because your users have been allowed to enter nonsense dates like `43/13/2047`, or you might have values like `13/01/2022` and `01/31/2022` and have no idea what date a value like `01/11/2023` is therefore meant to be.

Comment: [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934381/2029983) I've given in the past, which demonstrates how to add a *new* column with the correct data type, and how to find your old, bad, data.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a `VARCHAR` column, you will need to cast it to `DATETIME` to compare it.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, CreatedDate, 105) > '2023-11-01 12:15:32'
```

Try to use the dates as SQL gives it : yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: It's a much better idea to use this (or rather `TRY_CONVERT`) to permanently change the column, rather than repeat the conversion over and over again on every retrieval, which prohibits any use of indexes.